# php change array key with sub array value

Tags: php, array-key

```
[items] => stdClass Object
        (
            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 146300
                    [name]=>aa
                )
            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 146301
                    [name]=>bb
                )
)
----------------->changing to
[items] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ 146300] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] =>aa
                )
            [146301] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => bb
                )
)
```

how can i do without using foreach. is there any php array function?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this solution:

```
$result = array();
array_walk($data, function (&$value, &$key) use (&$result) {
    $result[$value->id] = $value;
    unset($result[$value->id]->id);
});
print_r($result);
```

> Only the values of the array may potentially be changed; its structure
>   cannot be altered, i.e., the programmer cannot add, unset or reorder
>   elements. If the callback does not respect this requirement, the
>   behavior of this function is undefined, and unpredictable.

More about `array_walk` in the [documentation](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

Comment: This snippet does not respect the top level property `items`.  This snippet produces an array of objects, not a three-level object.